# wmi c#. copy file from remote machine

Tags: c#, copy, wmi, remote-server

I use mgmtclassgen.exe and get wrapper(DataFile.cs) class for CIM_DataFile wmi class. Code below works perfect on localhost (without filling credentionals), but when I connect to remote machine variable returnResult=9 (Invalid object). But size of variable dataFileCollection=1

```
var _connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
                _connectionOptions.Username = "username";
                _connectionOptions.Password = "password";
                _connectionOptions.Authority = String.Format("ntlmdomain:{0}", "DOMAIN");
var _managementScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2",  
"RemotePCName"), _connectionOptions);
    var dataFileCollection = DataFile.GetInstances(_managementScope,
                    @"Name = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\mapisvc.inf'";
                var tempFilePath =  "c:\\temp.txt");
                if (dataFileCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var dataFile in dataFileCollection.Cast<DataFile>())
                    {
                        var returnResult = dataFile.Copy(tempFilePath);
                        if (File.Exists(tempFilePath))
                        {
                            List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(tempFilePath).ToList();
                            File.Delete(tempFilePath);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

try adjusting your management scope differently
Maybe you could try it like:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                        "\\\\" + strComputer + "\\root\\CIMV2",
                        "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerDatabases");
```

where strComputer is the name of the remote pc and Win32_Perf... the class you're trying to query. This works for me, as it is in a local network, though I am not certain where your remote machine is located.

You could as well to go http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572 which is a WMI-query generator by Microsoft. This allows you to generate query's in either C#, VB, and VB scripts. While setting the connection properties.
Might be worth a shot.